# PHP dom to get tag class with multiple css class name

Tags: php, css, class, dom

I have difficulties to get second link href and Text. How to select class="secondLink SecondClass". Using PHP Dom, Thank you

```
        <td class="pos" >
            <a class="firstLink" href="Search/?List=200003000112097&sr=1" >
                Firs link value
            </a>

            <br />

            <a class="secondLink SecondClass" href="/Search/?KeyOpt=ALL" >
                Second Link Value
            </a>
        </td
```

My code is

```
// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

// grab all the on the page

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
//$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a[@class='firstLink']");// its working

$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a[@class='secondLink SecondClass']");// not working
```

Thank you

Comment: Your [code is working](http://codepad.org/VZVUXgrT). The XPath is correct. You are doing something else wrong.

Comment: Wow.. its working. why its not working here. Thank you

Comment: doesn't work if you switch the class names around [see](http://codepad.org/TmzyWqUy)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' secondClass ')
          and (contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' secondLink '))]"
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662404/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-with-xpath)

Answer (score -1):

you can pick it by selecting your td having class pos and selecting anchor tags. then you cann control your returing array to get your specific anchor tag