# How to join two HtmlNodeCollections

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm usign [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in C# and I have two `HtmlNodeCollection`. Can I join both or is there other ways to get both in one `HtmlNodeCollection`?

One:

```
HtmlNodeCollection butiks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'butik-large-image')]");
```

Two:

```
HtmlNodeCollection butiks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'butik small left')]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HtmlNodeCollection` inherits `IList<HtmlNode>` which inherits `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` on which you can call the [`Enumerable.Concat()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) to create a new enumerable containing both sources. See [How to concatenate two IEnumerable<T> into a new IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164974/how-to-concatenate-two-ienumerablet-into-a-new-ienumerablet).

You can also just select both sets of nodes by [using an "or" in your Xpath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152890/xpath-contains-value-a-or-value-b):

```xml
//div[contains(@class,'butik-large-image') or contains(@class,'butik small left')]
```

Please note this `contains()` expects given classes in the given order. If you don't want that, use parentheses and `and`:

```xml
//div[contains(@class,'butik-large-image') 
or 
( 
    contains(@class,'left') and
    contains(@class,'small') and
    contains(@class,'butik')
)]
```

See [How can I select an element with multiple classes with Xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662404/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-with-xpath) for a proper implementation of that `and`, as above code will match false positives because it doesn't check for the classes as separate words.

Comment: if my class attribute have to class link this `class='butik large'` can i use this way?

Comment: @AHIR, see the or- and and-conditions, just add the ones you need. It's a simple boolean expression, it can grow as wide or narrow as you please.