# How to write xpath with same class but different index?

Tags: xpath

I want to get the SECOND one with same class. inside there's the link.

```
<ul>
    <li class="arrow">
        <a href="somelinks.com"> </a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="arrow">
        <a href="someotherlinkstopage.com"> </a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

i wanna get the "someotherlinkstopage.com". It's the second last li. should i try second last li? or go with class?

i tried :

```
//(li[contains(@class,'arrow'])[2]/a/@href

//li[contains(@class, 'arrow')][2]/a/@href

//li[@class='arrow'][2]/a/@href
```

Answer (score 2):

You were very close.  The following XPath,

```
(//li[@class = 'arrow'])[2]/a/@href
```

will select `"someotherlinkstopage.com"` as requested.

You can also use `contains()` in this case, but beware of matches against `arrows`, `sparrow`, etc.   See [How can I select an element with multiple classes with Xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662404/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-with-xpath)

Comment: Your second and third tries, as well as the solution I provided, will work on the sample HTML you've shown.   If you're not having success with my or your second two solutions, then you've not provided a representative HTML excerpt.

Comment: i checked html.. only contains two "arrow".. i really dont know why.. and before this i didnt realise it has 2 "arrow", i code //li[contains(@class, 'arrow')]/a/@href , it went to the second page then it stopped.. but it scraped 1st and second page..

Comment: shouldi go for "second" last li? last()-1?

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this using

```
(//li[@class='arrow'])[last()]/a/@href
```

i've no idea why [2] can't be used but last() can..

but i know i use last() because there's only 2 class named arrow.. either first or last.

Comment: Creating a proper **[mcve]** is hard but saves both your time and ours in the long run.