# xpath - Get href attribute

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get all `href` links via xpath from the following page:

[href page](http://www.home24.at/schlafzimmermoebel/matratzen/)

I tried the following:

```
//div[@class='article-tile__images']/a[@class='article-tile__link js-article-tile__link acte-article-catalogName-lnk']
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `xmllint --html` throws an enormous number of errors about the page: XPath is going to be dodgy as a result.

Comment: @bishop, unfortunately, I think that xmllint is not yet aware of HTML5 tags and rejects them. There is probably a way to feed the correct "DTD" although HTML5 does not offer such per se... (since it's really extensible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with `class` attributes is much easier, readable and concise in CSS selectors:

```
a.article-tile__link
```

which matches 65 links when I issue `$$('a.article-tile__link')` in the Chrome console.

Comment: Thx for your quick answer! How would the above look in xpath?

Comment: @mrquad well, the simplest one would be `//a[contains(@class, "article-tile__link")]`. But, if you are going to stick to xpath here, better use `concat()` to handle multiple classes more reliably and avoid surprises, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662452/771848. Thanks.