# PHP XML/HTML DOM get CSS class attribute with whitespace

Tags: php, xml, dom, css

I've got the following problem:
I'm using the PHP XML DOM parser and when I'm parsing real-world HTML, the 'class' attributes of many elements have spaces in them, so there are actually multiple CSS classes for these elements. However, when I query the DOMNode with getAttribute(), I'm getting only the first class.

I have also tried PHP simplehtmldom for the very same purpose, but to the same result.

This question has been asked here before, however not really answered:
[PHP dom to get tag class with multiple css class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835300/php-dom-to-get-tag-class-with-multiple-css-class-name)

This workaround does not work in my case. Any help would be appreciated :)

The other question contains a very good example of what I need to accomplish in case anyone did not understand me.

Comment: there seems to be a working code example, have you tried that?

Comment: If you're referring to the code in the question itself, it only demonstrates the problem I'm trying to solve :( Sadly it does not work out the issue.

Comment: no the code link in the comment that say's its working http://codepad.org/VZVUXgrT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for the example in the stackoveflow question you linked to. Works for me:

```
$body = // the html
$html = new DomDocument();
$html->loadHTML($body);
$as = $html->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($as as $a) { 
    if ($a->getAttribute('class')=='secondLink SecondClass') {
          // do something
    }
 }
```

Comment: OK, I can't reproduce the correct behavior, but I'll check the configuration on my end. If I can't find anything, I'm accepting your answer

Comment: Did you get it to work? What seems to be not working? Can you post the full code that you used?