# how to get div class value using dom document

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domdocument

how to get div class value using dom document

i need to echo this value `4,458 members`

from the below code

```
< div class="mbs fcg">4,458 members< /div>
```

right now my orginal code is

```
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($links as $link){

echo $link->nodeValue;
echo $link->getAttribute('class');

}
```

how to target this particular `class = mbc fcg` ?

now with my present code i am getting all div values.

what changes i should do

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP XML/HTML DOM get CSS class attribute with whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465557/php-xml-html-dom-get-css-class-attribute-with-whitespace)

Comment: It is unclear what you want: 1) you ask to target a `class value`. 2) You want to echo a `text-node` ... So, what do you actually want?

Comment: sir, what i want is <div class="mbs fcg">4,458 members< /div> in this code i want to scrape this value 4,458 members

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835300/php-dom-to-get-tag-class-with-multiple-css-class-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), which will take a DOMDocument instance

```
$xpath   = new DOMXPath( $dom );
// if the className doesn`t changes
$members = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="mbs fcg"]' );
// if the class name changes ex. class="mbs fcg my-other class-name"
$members = $xpath->query( '//div[contains(@class,"mbs fcg")]' );
```

alternatively if you want to iterate all over your div`s you could try

```
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
foreach( $divs as $div ){
    // if the className doesn`t changes
    if( $div->getAttribute( 'class' ) === 'mbs fcg' ){
        echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
    // if the class name changes ex. class="mbs fcg my-other class-name"
    if( strpos( $div->getAttribute( 'class' ), 'mbs fcg' ) !== false ){
        echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: your welcome, i'm glad i could help you out. you should also mark it as right answer

Answer (score 1):

NOTICE:::
THIS IS A JAVASCRIPT SOLUTION ... NOT A PHP DOMDOCUMENT SOLUTION

Try this HTML:

```
<div id="ME" class="mbs fcg">4,458 members</div>
```

... and this Javascript:

```
var WANTED_TEXT = document.getElementById('ME').firstChild.nodeValue;
```

EDIT2:

If you actually want, to get all textnodes from all occurrences of elements having `class='mbs cfg'` ... then try the following HTML:

```
<div class="mbs fcg">4,458 members</div>
```

... and this Javascript:

```
var Collection = document.getElementsByClassName('mbs fcg');

for(i=0; i<Collection.length; i++) {
    Texts = Collection[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    document.write('<p>'+Texts+'</p>');
}
```

That should echo the pure text from all elements in the Collection.

Comment: i dont have option to add div id sir. cos i am scrapping from other website

Comment: without using javascript can we scrape sir, i mean with the help of domdocument i want to scrap

Comment: I havn't tried myself ... But, I would think so, yes.

Comment: Ohhh ... this is PHP only ... sorry ... I didn’t notice that! ... You should disregard my answer, which is a JavaScript solution.

Comment: its ok sir, do u have any id how we can write in php

Comment: I read, that DOMDocument doesn't offer a method `getElementsByClassName` to select by `class`, but only offers selection either by `id` or by `tagName` ... that means you need to collect all divs, and then iterate to find your class-names by string-comparison or regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an `id` to target a single `div`, such as:

```
< div id="my_id_name" class="mbs fcg">4,458 members< /div>
```

Comment: sorry i cannot add div id, i need to scrape the data from other website. i only have to scrape <div class="mbs fcg">