# PHP Simple HTML DOM parser - print class name

Tags: php, class, parsing, dom

I have little problem with parsing some data from one webpage. 
I'm trying to get class name of certain `div`.

Example:

```
< div class="stars b3"></div>
```

I want to save in array just `b3`. 
Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835300/php-dom-to-get-tag-class-with-multiple-css-class-name

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
<?php // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835300/php-dom-to-get-tag-class-with-multiple-css-class-name

$html = <<< HTML
<td class="pos" >
    <a class="firstLink" href="Search/?List=200003000112097&sr=1" >
        Firs link value
    </a>

    <br />

    <a class="secondLink SecondClass" href="/Search/?KeyOpt=ALL" >
        Second Link Value
    </a>
</td
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate(
    "/html/body//a[@class='secondLink SecondClass']"
);
echo $hrefs->item(0)->getAttribute('class');
```

Ref.  http://codepad.org/VZVUXgrT

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I already saw this solution, but i don't know how to use this with Php Simple DOM library.

Its possible to use getAttribute with this library or i just dont know right sintax.

Comment: You should be able to grab all attributes from a tag (such as the `class` tag) like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456621/simple-html-dom-getting-all-attributes-from-a-tag Example shows `a` tag, but you should be able to modify to get the `class` tag.  **Really, you should just be able to use your current code and simply `explode()` the value to get all the classes individually.**

Comment: $a->attr this is what i was looking for.
Thanks again!